# Missing post data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am submitting my post form in CodeIgniter but I am only getting the last table row commited.
Does any one here know why?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/admin/myform"; ?>" method="post">
    <table>
    <?php foreach($arrays as $row) { // 10 times <tr></tr> ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><input type="text" name="colOne" value="<?php echo $row->ColOne; ?>"> <input type="text" name="colTwo" value="<?php echo $row->ColTwo; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><input style="width:100%;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
    </form>
```

This is the Controller content:
        $data = array();

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $sql = $this->db->query("UPDATE myWebApp
                               SET ColOne = '".$this->input->post('colOne')."',
                               ColTwo = '".$this->input->post('colTwo')."'
                               WHERE id = ".$this->input->post('id'));

        if($sql) {      
            $data = array('Status' => $this->input->post());
            // $this->input->post() contains always only the last array (the 10th) instead of all ten arrays
        } else {
            $data = array('Status' => 'No success. Sorry.');
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inputs all share the same "name" attribute :

```
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id"...
</tr>
```

To HTML, it's the name of the input that counts. You need to make the name dynamic if you want to avoid the overwriting.

Maybe some like this?

```
<tr>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="id_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
<input type="text" name="colOne_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->ColOne; ?>"> 
<input type="text" name="colTwo_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->ColTwo; ?>">
</td>
</tr>
```

...assuming $row->id is a database unique ID.

Comment: You could also use an array: `name='id[]'` or `name="id[<?php echo $row->id; ?>]"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

All of your fields have the same name, so they are all being overridden.  You need to change the name to `id[]` (and so on).  The `[]` makes PHP see it as an array.

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="colOne[]" value="<?php echo $row->ColOne; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="colTwo[]" value="<?php echo $row->ColTwo; ?>">
</td>
```

Doing that will make `$this->input->post('colOne')`, `$this->input->post('colTwo')` and `$this->input->post('id')` into arrays.